# How to Set Focus on Input Field using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="http://example.com" class="link">click here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="post">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
<div>
```

which will be repeated several times on the page, how do I set the focus on the input field in the `.bottom` div when a user clicks on the link in the `.top` div?

I am currently making the `.bottom` div appear successfully on click using the JQuery code below, but can't seem to figure out how to set focus on the input field at the same time.

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.bottom').show();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has been answered, but also:  I assume you are also executing `return false;` at the end of the event callback? Or `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ..... }`?  If not, your browser will just navigate to that page after it executes the callback.

Comment: @simshaun navigate to which page?

Comment: Well, in your example when you click that link it would go to http://example.com.

Comment: oh, that's right, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Try this, to set the focus to the first input field:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('div.bottom').find("input.post").focus();
```

Comment: Space between `input` & `:first`.  Does jQuery splice that automatically? I've always thought it should be `input:first`.

Comment: Yes, you can write it either way. I suppose `input:first` might be the more formal way to write it, although it seems easier to read the other way. But maybe that's just me :)

Comment: I guess that because I'm so used to it, when I see the space I automatically think "child element" and it takes a second to de-confuse myself.  But hey, that's just me.  It's cool that it works either way.

Comment: @justin i actually had to tweak it a little to make it work: `$(this).parent().siblings('div.bottom').find("input.post").focus();` but `.find()` is the selector I was looking for. Interestingly `input :first` nor `input:first` worked.

Comment: Interesting, probably because the input is within a `form` tag. Anyway, glad you go it to work!

Comment: jQuery's .focus() function is for adding a handler for the event emitted when the input gets the focus. This does not set focus on an input. Downvoted.

Comment: @KevinBuchs - It can either bind an event handler to the "focus" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element. Read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) for the third variation of `focus` and see the example at the bottom.

Answer (score 27):

If the input happens to be in a bootstrap modal dialog, the answer is different. Copying from [How to Set focus to first text input in a bootstrap modal after shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247849/how-to-set-focus-to-first-text-input-in-a-bootstrap-modal-after-shown)  this is what is required:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#textareaID').focus();
})
```

Comment: Nice! Just what i needed, and have been debugging for a couple of hours, tried delay and all kinda hacks... :-)

Comment: Also don't forget to put this in under document.ready or something equivalent to that (form load event).

Answer (score 8):

Justin's answer did not work for me (Chromium 18, Firefox 43.0.1). jQuery's `.focus()` creates visual highlight, but text cursor does not appear in the field (jquery 3.1.0).

Inspired by https://www.sitepoint.com/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/ , I added **autofocus** attribute to the input field and voila!

```
function addfield() {
    n=$('table tr').length;
    $('table').append('<tr><td><input name=field'+n+' autofocus></td><td><input name=value'+n+'></td></tr>');
    $('input[name="aa"'+n+']').focus();
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Simpler version is like this: 
            $('.class input').focus();
            $('.class input').prop('autofocus');

Answer (score 2):

```
//$GLOBALS['sitename'] is our domain site URL
//$_GET['s'] is the search parameter of our search, and we want to highlight that term searched...    
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
        let loc=location.href;
        switch(loc) 
        {

    case "<?php echo $GLOBALS['sitename'] ?>?s=<?php echo $_GET['s'] ?>":       
        {       
        let searchf= $("form.search-form").find("input[type='search']:first");
//searchf.val('').focus();      
//empty the value to allow a new search and focus on the field....this works but better to highlight the searched term to allow the user to decide if want to type in something else or just hit again search. In case we want to empty the searched term 
           setTimeout(function (){
           searchf.delay(1000).focus().select(); 
           }, 1000);    
        break;
//.... end of relevant code 
        }
```