# focus for textfield in a twitter bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I need to have the focus for textfield in a twitter bootstrap modal dialog.I have tried the focus() method.

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/XexYGBkay5)**

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
  initialize();
});
function initialize(){

    $('#my').val('');/*empty the textfield for each time
    dialog is called */
   $('#my').focus();//to get focus
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Open modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <input type="text" id="my" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247849/how-to-set-focus-to-first-text-input-in-a-bootstrap-modal-after-shown), Though I did try implementing the solution with your Bootply and it didn't help. I'll keep looking into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here are a few pointers. With Bootstrap 3.x there is a function that is triggered by the modal.shown event called thusly, `$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', funciton() {...})` which is used to do what your `initialize()` function is doing. To fix the issue with `focus()` you have to add the following line to your code:

`$("#my").ready(function() {...})`

The problem is that the input isn't fully ready in the DOM, so you must wait for it to be loaded and ready before you try manipulating it.  [Here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is more documentation on the `.ready()` function.

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/DLgDp/)

Comment: If this solution is what you are looking for, please accept the answer :) ps. Thanks for the challenge. I've never run into this bug before. I've always relied on the solution [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252413/2041091)

Comment: thanks for the well researched solution. I improvised on the solution and textfield is first made empty before the ready function.[link](http://jsfiddle.net/DLgDp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

***Code Snippet for showing the dialog***

```
$('#openBtn').click(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    $('#my').val('');//empting the textfield so that dialog does not retain previous state
});
```

***not using the ready function,using only modal shown event***

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#my").focus();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DLgDp/5/)**

Comment: I feel like this was just one of those 'Duh...' moments... I can't believe I didn't see this earlier. Thanks for posting this after the fact!