# Focus input on modal show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I auto focus an input on modal show? Currently I do this but it isn't working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
        $('input[name="myInput"]').focus();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/2513/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set focus to first text input in a bootstrap modal after shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247849/how-to-set-focus-to-first-text-input-in-a-bootstrap-modal-after-shown)

Comment: Possibly you want shown.bs.modal instead of show.bs.modal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is basically correct. But the event `show.bs.modal` is triggerede **before** the modal has been shown. You need to use `shown.bs.modal` event instead.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('input[name="myInput"]').focus();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/2544/

Comment: `$('input[name="myInput"]').focus();` did not work for me, but `$('#myInput').focus();` did work - thanks! (Bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 0):

In Your code, Use `autofocus`

`<input name="myInput" value="MyVal" type="text" autofocus/>`

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#youModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('input[name="youInputText"]').focus();
    });
});
```

For WordPress:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('#youModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        jQuery('input[name="youInputText"]').focus();
    });
});
```